# glDeleteFramebuffers delete framebuffer object, does it delete texture attached to this framebuffer?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

Platform: Android OpenGL ES 2.0

I am using FBO, there is a texture attached to this FBO, after use, I use glDeleteFramebuffers to release FBO, the question is: Do I need to manually release the texture I created also? or glDeleteFramebuffers will also release the texture attached to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would have thought you'd have to release each texture that you've created as well. There should be a *delete* call for every *create* call.

Comment: @Eric: Also note that if you delete a texture while it is attached to an FBO, the actual memory will not be freed until it is detached from any and all FBOs. All that will happen is that the name (id) goes up into the list of "free" texture names for re-use. The data store will persist in order to prevent the FBO from invoking undefined behavior, pretty much all container objects in OpenGL/ES work this way: VAOs, FBOs, GLSL programs, etc.